# Annoying "Controlled folder access" popup after Windows 10 v1803 upgrade

Tags: windows-defender, windows-10-v1803, controlled-folder-access

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 v1803 (last night, as the update finally came out through Windows Update for my computer). However, I am now constantly getting this popup on my desktop.

[image: Controlled folder access blocked C:...\DDVDataCollector... from making changes to memory.]

It's happening so much, I get a notification every 5-10 minutes. Also, I didn't get this popup in Windows 10 v1709.

What I want to know is:

1. What is DDVDataCollector? I can't find it in my programs list, and the notification won't tell me.
2. How do I stop this? It won't tell me the full path to the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is DDVDataCollector?

It's a folder created by a Dell OEM program software package installed on your machine. The folder was created by the Dell software.  The folder in question was created by `Dell Data Vault` and is installed by default on your system.

> How do I stop this?

Just turn off `Controlled Folder Access`

[image]

> It won't tell me the full path to the program.

You can also just disable Controlled Folder Access to specific folders if you want.  Just remove the folder in question.  On the same screen as above, there will be a way, to remove specific folders.

You can find the full path of the folder by using Windows Search.

[image]

> I didn't get this popup in Windows 10 v1709.

Controlled Folder Access was indeed a feature of 1709.  You might have enabled it without realizing when you upgraded to 1803.  You could also just give Dell Data Vault permission to modify the folder.  The application executables can be located at `C:\Program Files\Dell\DellDataVault`

[image]

It might be worth pointing out.  If you are connected to an Active Directory domain, a group policy can configure which folders are protected, if that is the case contact your System Administrator and have them remove the folder from the list of protected folders.

Comment: As for the reason this just started to happen. It's likely a bug in Dell's software. If you don't need the software just uninstall it.  How you remove `Dell Data Vault` is a separate question.  So I just suggest removing all Dell software (if you are authorized to do that), that will get rid of the software in question.  Otherwise, you should research, which Dell software package contains this application.  I found far to many possible candidates to come to the conclusion myself.

Comment: I did have Controlled folder access on in Windows 10 v1709 (I remember having to allow programs like VMware through it) but thanks! Apparently the memory restrictions were an added feature in v1803, which would explain why the issue wasn't present in v1709.